# C Bus Error with mmap, what is the problem

Tags: c

For a homework assignment my prof wants us to read a file using mmap. Then copy it to another file using memcpy after mmap-ing the destination file.
I think i am doing this correctly, but C disagrees.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep
#include <time.h> // for the timeing of execution


// for reading and writing the files:
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <string.h>

// create status struct for passing arguments to the threads
typedef struct threadComms{
    char* source;
    char* destination;

    double total_time;
    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;

    // to use the timeing functions,
    // when the thread starts, 'start = clock();'
    // when the thread ends, 'end = clock();'
    // 'total_time = end - start;'
} ThreadComms;


size_t getFileSize(char* filePath){

    struct stat st;
    stat(filePath, &st);

    return st.st_size;
}

void copyFile(void* arg){ // this needs to be a void* for the pthread library


    ThreadComms* comms = (ThreadComms*) arg;
    // start the counter
    comms->start = clock();

    size_t fileSize = getFileSize(comms->source);

    int sfd = open(comms->source, O_RDONLY, 0);

    assert(sfd != -1); // failed to open the file

    void* content = mmap(NULL, fileSize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FILE, sfd, 0); // map the file into the address space

    assert(content != MAP_FAILED);
    printf("data: %s\n", (char*) content);

    int dfd = open(comms->destination, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    assert(dfd != -1); // failed to create the file

    printf("fileSize: %d\n", (int) fileSize);

    printf("1\n");
    void* destination = mmap(NULL, fileSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE,  dfd, 0);
    printf("2 destination is: %p\n", destination);

    memcpy(destination, content, fileSize);
    printf("3\n");

    comms->end = clock();
    comms->total_time = ((double) (comms->end - comms->start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ThreadComms t1;
    char* filePath = "/home/csis/tempFile";
    char* newFile =  "/home/csis/tempFile2";

    t1.source = filePath;
    t1.destination = newFile;
    copyFile(&t1);

//  printf("Start: %f, End: %f, Run Time: %f \n", (double)t1.start, (double)t1.end , (double)t1.total_time);
}
```

I am guessing that i am using my file descriptor for the destination incorrectly or giving it the wrong permissions.
Wondering if you have any guess as to what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `gdb`?

Comment: You create a 0-size file and then `mmap()` it with the size of the source ?

Comment: Why are you doing a second mmap? That's useless. Just `write` the data to the second file.

Comment: @Unimportant I have not tried gdb, which is why i have all the printf's in the code. I am not at all proficient with it and can never seem to get it to work.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli The assignment says that we need to do a second mmap, then use memcpy to copy the data from one file to the other.

Comment: @marcolz We need to use mmap to create the file.

Comment: *We need to use mmap to create the file.*  That's, umm, confusing.  `mmap()` can only map files that already exist (or it can map anonymous memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write to a non-existent portion of a file via `mmap()`.

This truncates the file:

```
int dfd = open(comms->destination, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

This `mmap()`'s the truncated file:

```
void* destination = mmap(NULL, fileSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE,  dfd, 0);
```

This tries to copy to a non-existent part of the file:

```
memcpy(destination, content, fileSize);
```

Per the [Linux `mmap()` man page **ERRORS**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> **ERRORS**
>
> ...
>
> Use of a mapped region can result in these signals:
>
> ...
>
> `SIGBUS` Attempted access to a portion of the buffer that does not
>                 correspond to the file (for example, beyond the end of the
>                 file, including the case where another process has truncated
>                 the file).

Per [the POSIX `mmap()` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html):

> ... References within the address range starting at pa and continuing for len bytes to whole pages following the end of an object shall result in delivery of a `SIGBUS` signal.
>
> An implementation may generate `SIGBUS` signals when a reference would cause an error in the mapped object, such as out-of-space condition.

The fix is to call `ftruncate()` to set the file length on the output file:

```
ftruncate( dfd, fileSize );
void* destination = mmap(NULL, fileSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,  dfd, 0);
```

Note that you also have to replace the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag with `MAP_SHARED`.  [Per POSIX again](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) (bolding mine):

> `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_PRIVATE` describe the disposition of write references to the memory object. **If `MAP_SHARED` is specified, write references shall change the underlying object. `If MAP_PRIVATE` is specified, modifications to the mapped data by the calling process shall be visible only to the calling process and shall not change the underlying object.** It is unspecified whether modifications to the underlying object done after the `MAP_PRIVATE` mapping is established are visible through the `MAP_PRIVATE` mapping. Either `MAP_SHARED` or `MAP_PRIVATE` can be specified, but not both. The mapping type is retained across `fork()`.

Comment: You omitted the fix: OP needs to call `ftruncate` to set the dest file's size before memcpy'ing into the map. It doesn't matter whether you do that before or after the `mmap`.

Comment: @R.. Still working on it.  I was looking up the POSIX specification.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Great, but when i run that i go from a source file that has ascii text to garbage in the output file. Any thoughts? "^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@"

Comment: @BendeVries Is the destination file the correct size?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, the source is 10 bytes, after running the code the destination file is 10 bytes as well.

Comment: You're missing a crucial step: `msync(destination, fileSize, MS_SYNC);` and also `munmap()` at the end.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli `msync()` is not necessary.  `MAP_SHARED` is.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it is. From the man page: *"msync()  flushes changes made to the in-core copy of a file that was mapped into memory using mmap(2) back to the filesystem.  Without use of this call, there is no guarantee that changes are written  back  before  munmap(2)  is  called."*. Either you correctly `munmap()`, or you `msync()`. Doing both is best.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli `munmap()` is done on process exit.  [Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01): "Any blocks of typed memory that were mapped in the calling process shall be unmapped, as if `munmap()` was implicitly called to unmap them."  So there's no need to explicitly call `munmap()`.

Comment: I know, but I would call that bad practice to be honest. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MarcoBonelli True, but the lack of an explicit `msync()` or `munmap()` shouldn't be causing any significant problems here - it would just be a few millisecond window added for a failure to erase the changes - but the OP's code doesn't check for any errors and falls off `main()` to return zero no matter what happens.  If high availablity and data integrity were important, the implicit `munmap()` is certainly not a good practice.

Comment: I appreciate the back and forth, but wondering if there is a solution? Or if any of you are able to reproduce the error i am having?

Comment: @BendeVries Did you change the `mmap()` call for the destination to use `MAP_SHARED`?

Comment: Okay, well this is embarrassing. I opened the output file with the wrong params. char* destination = mmap(NULL, fileSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE, MAP_SHARED, dfd, 0); is what the mmap line should have read. Thanks for all the help guys.